# Allwinner A20 power up pin?

Tags: soc

I am working on a design using an Allwinner A20 SoC, but I am after quite a lot of googling, unable to find the Power On pin, or any pin that is normally used to initiate the power up, would it be safe to assume it will power up when power is applied to all Power pins?

Comment: Is there a reset pin?

Comment: It has a, RESET# but, its in the JTAG section.

Comment: It's in the "System Control" section of the [A20 brief](http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/A20/A20%20Brief%202013-02-27.pdf) (p16).

Comment: See also P33 of that document.

Comment: This was closed after I accepted an answer? For what reason?

Comment: No idea why it was closed. There's nothing particularly unclear here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a "power on" pin per-say, but as with many SoC's and MCUs, they have a "reset" pin which does much the same function.

As per the table on page 16 of the [A20 Product Brief](http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/A20/A20%20Brief%202013-02-27.pdf), the A20 does indeed have a reset pin.

Furthermore, if you refer to page 33, you can see the intended power on sequence. First you apply power, while holding the reset pin low (asserted). Once the power is stabilised, you can then release the chip from reset by pulling the pin high. This ensures that none of the logic ends up in a weird state while the power is ramping up.

Comment: What would be a good way of verifying the stability of the power?

Comment: There are ICs available - so called power monitors or reset monitors which compare the supply voltage with a reference and once it is high enough they deassert the reset after a few milliseconds.